# What's the most distant radio message we could detect with today's radio telescopes, if the message is initially broadcasted in all directions?

Tags: radio-telescope, seti

An additional assumption is that broadcasting the message may require using a medium-sized star, like the Sun, for an hour, by e.g. Dysoning it.

I don't know enough to answer the question myself. If the question needs more details filled in to be well-formed, you can make additional assumptions.

Comment: What is the furthest medium sized star we can see in radio waves? That will be a good start point.

Comment: Note "energy" and "power" are different things.  We'd normally worry about either the power of a sustained signal or the total energy of a single burst.  The total energy of a star would be of the order of it's entire mass converted to energy which is more than the star would normally emit in it's lifetime (as the total mass is never completely converted to energy).  Also note [worldbuilding.se] if this relates to some sort of fictional world building - they do deal with science questions there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @StephenG-HelpUkraine, I've edited the question to better specify what I meant.